# Swords/action/fantasy/magic anime: main character is a bit of a failure, always follows the rules and carries a sword, unlocks his magical ability

Tags: story-identification, magic, anime

I saw an anime quite a long time ago and for the life of me I can't remember what the name of it is.

It's a magic/fighting/fantasy based anime and the main character is fighting, and then there is another entity that appears, he then gains this kind of ability, and gets given this kind of armour. Main character,

- Seen as a bit of a failure but has a very can-do attitude, and he always follows the rules -always carries a sword -there is a uniform that the characters in the team all wear, think there is black and green colours predominantly,
- Doesn't show much magical ability but doesn't really need it because he is really good with the sword
- His colleagues all have magical abilities, or powers etc…
- As he is fighting in one of the episodes he all of a sudden shows this hidden magical ability and gains a suit of armour

I know it doesn't seem like much, but those are the only things I can really remember about it.

Comment: I'm thinking Black Clover.

Comment: Can you describe the armor?  Does it cover his face?  What color is it? Does it look more like plate or like a mecha?

Comment: or do you remember any details on WHOM they are fighting? monsters, ...?

Comment: How long ago was quite a long time ago? 90’s? 80’s? Mid 2000’s?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [“The Irregular at Magic High School”](https://myanimelist.net/anime/20785/Mahouka_Koukou_no_Rettousei) to me.

The main character is known as a “weed” which is a reserve course student. He is the “Irregular” because he is one of the best at the school despite his poor Magic ability and class. This matches up to the description of a character who is seen as a “failure” yet keeps his head up and is quite skilled physically. There’s also the fact that his friends all have magic abilities as mentioned and the uniforms contain black and green as main colors (along with white.)

[image: high schoolers in green and white uniforms]

Comment: Hi, could you add some notes that show how this matches the points in the question?  Check out [answer] for more help.

Comment: The MC does not use a sword. He carries 2 guns.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i can think of is Akame ga Kill ? 
The main character is good with a sword but generally not that strong. 
Then he kinda of inherits this suit of armour that makes him stronger.